# GKE: Scheduled Jobs

Tags: google-kubernetes-engine

Anyone knows if Scheduled Jobs is already available in GKE 1.4.3?

I get the following when I try to deploy

```
error validating "letsencrypt-sj.yaml": error validating data: couldn't find type: v2alpha1.ScheduledJob; if you choose to ignore these errors, turn validation off with --validate=fals
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Scheduled Jobs are currently an alpha feature in Kubernetes 1.4, so they are not available in a normal GKE cluster (because alpha features are subject to breaking changes at any time).

Until Scheduled Jobs reach beta status and become available by default, you can create an [alpha cluster](https://cloud.google.com/container-engine/docs/alpha-clusters) to test them in GKE.

Comment: Needs a comment right below:  Alpha clusters only persist for 30 days.  I just want to emphasize this point.